# Cannot instantiate abstract class: Why is the template parameter (reference) causing this?

Tags: c++, templates, abstract

I am having trouble with some code.

> 'Bar' : cannot instantiate abstract class

I have (finally) been able to recreate the error in a small amount of code.

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    // ******
};

template <typename TIN, typename TOUT, typename TINDEX>
struct IFoo
{
public:
    virtual void add(const TIN item) = 0; // <-- BAD
    //virtual void add(const TOUT& item) = 0; // <-- GOOD

    // ******
};

template <typename TVALUE, typename TINDEX>
struct Bar : IFoo<TVALUE &, TVALUE, TINDEX>
{

public:

    void add(const TVALUE& item)
    {
        // ******
    }

    // ******
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SomeStruct someStruct;
    Bar<SomeStruct, int> bar = Bar<SomeStruct, int>();
    bar.add(someStruct);

    // ******
}
```

Can anyone please advise WHY using a reference with the template parameter is causing this?

Comment: because you are implementing in Bar `add(const TVALUE&)`, with reference. It's a different function than the one declared as pure virtual in base class

Comment: You would see what @Hcorg said is true by modifying the definition in `Bar` to `void add(const TVALUE& item) override;` and the compiler would tell you that you aren't overriding a function from the base class.

Comment: That's not the issue here, as `TIN` is `TOUT&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that when you write `const TIN` and `TIN` is a reference type, the `const` applies to the *reference* and not to the value type.

This is why you are seeing different behaviour for `const TIN` and `const TOUT&` even when you think they should be the same.

A simple fix for this is to add the `const` to the value type in your `IFoo` instantiation:

```
struct Bar : IFoo<const TVALUE &, TVALUE, TINDEX>
//          here  ^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem goes back to basic concepts like function signature: a function signature/prototype is given by the function name, the number of parameters, datatype of parameters and the order of appearance of those parameters.

For any two functions if any of the above differ, than you are dealing with two different functions.

More exactly, these two represent two different signatures:

```
virtual void add(const TIN item) = 0; 
virtual void add(const TOUT& item) = 0;
```

Since you implement only the second one in the derived class, you get the error.

Comment: @Beakie: If `TIN == TOUT&`, `const TIN` is still different from `const TOUT&`. In that case `const TIN` is still just `TOUT&`, which is not the same as `const TOUT&`.

Comment: the first function accepts as parameter a variable of type TIN, the second one accepts a reference to a variable. So even is TIN and TOUT are the same data type, a reference type and a variable are not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

We can simply your example further to:

```
template <typename T>
struct IFoo {
    virtual void add(const T item) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar : IFoo<T&> {
    void add(const T& item) { }
};
```

In `Bar`, you are taking `item` as a reference to `const T`. In `IFoo`, you are declaring a pure virtual method that takes a `const` reference to `T`. But all references are inherently `const`, so that's redundant - it's equivalent to just taking a reference to `T`.

For `Bar<int>` - the signature of `IFoo::add()` is `void add(int& )` whereas `Bar::add()` is `void add(const int& )`. Those signatures don't match - hence `Bar` is still an abstract class. Just one that hid `IFoo::add()`.

If you have a C++11 compiler, you should prefer to add the `override` keyword to `Bar::add()` so that you would get a compiler error for:

```
main.cpp:15:10: error: 'void Bar<T>::add(const T&) [with T = int]' marked 'override', but does not override
     void add(const T& ) override { }
          ^
```